# 「侵入したのが〇〇」なぜ「は」ではなく「が」でしょうか

Tags: は-and-が

最近この文章を見かけました。

> 中王国はエジプト初の外来民族の侵入によって衰退しました。侵入したの**が**混成民族集団ヒクソス。これがアジア方面から侵入した。

太字にした「が」は、なぜ「は」ではないのでしょうか。前の文では、ある侵入が起こったことがすで述べられたので、問題の文の目的は侵入したのは誰かということになるのではないでしょうか。したがって、その文の焦点が「侵入したの」ではなく、「混成民族集団ヒクソス」だとすれば、「侵入したの**は**」の方が相応しいのではないでしょうか。「が」を使ってしまうと、焦点が「侵入したの」に置かれることになりませんか。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: Has the Hyksos already been introduced in the discourse (before your citation)? Or is this the first time the author mentioned the name of Hyksos?

Comment: @naruto This is the first time.

Comment: @lightweaver What comes after? Is what follows it the description of Hyksos, the event, or another event?

Comment: @broccoliforest What directly follows is this: 「ヒクソスの侵入で馬と戦車がはじめてエジプトにもたらされました。それまでのエジプトには馬がいなかったわけだから、どれだけ孤立した世界だったかわかりますね。」What then follows is a discussion on the use of horses in war at the time, ending with 「その馬と戦車にエジプトは征服されますが、やがてエジプトはこの新戦法を自分のものにしてヒクソスを追い出した。できたのが新王国。」The Hyksos are never mentioned thereafter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 中王国はエジプト初の外来民族の侵入によって衰退しました。侵入したのが混成民族集団ヒクソス。これがアジア方面から侵入した。

この場合は**が**を繰り返して、著者は当該の民族集団を具体的な事柄として強調したいのではないでしょうか。

> 侵入したの**が**混成民族集団ヒクソス。これ**が**アジア方面から侵入した。

に対して、

> 侵入したの**は**混成民族集団ヒクソス。これ**が**アジア方面から侵入した。

**は**を用いると単なる事実の羅列、ある意味世界史の教科書的な書き方のように思えます。

**が**を二度繰り返すと、少なからず緊迫感のあるテレビのドキュメンタリーの様な映像を思い浮かべやすいと思います。